# Inject model field in onclick event of input in Razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My client side scripting is rough and I just started with Razor. I haven't been able to find a way to do the following, where I want to inject a model field value within the onclick confirmation message:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ManageLocations", new { id = @Model.Location.Id }))
                   { <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete @Model.Location.DisplayLocation ?');" value="Delete">}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops, stupid mistake...I was embedding this BeginForm within another....The reason this does not work is you cannot have one form nested within another.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't know exactly how to answer this any clearer. The problem was that I had nested BeginForm statements, which is not allowed.